# My EIN or LLC isn't registering for some reason

Tags: twilio

I am trying to sign up for a Primary Business profile. I have entered in all my details for my business, but when I try to proceed, it does not allow me.

I am wondering if I possibly missed a field? It seem to be not taking my EIN or LLC name for some reason, can you help me with this?

I tried entering in my info but it is not letting me continue.

Comment: Contact Twilio support. We can't do anything here.